# Understanding Problem - Jquery Deferred chaining

Tags: jquery, promise, deferred

```
function ajax_call() {

    var ajaxCallMock = $.Deferred().resolve('A');

    return ajaxCallMock.done(function(response) {

            return 'B';

    });
}



ajax_call().done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

I would expect the console output to be 'B', but I get 'A'. Why?

Comment: Because you can only resolve a promise once AFAIK

Comment: I think a resolved promise always returns another solved promise, is that wrong?

Comment: Oh, I missed the `done` part, sorry

Comment: jQuery's `.done()` is not a synonym for `.then()`. There are few if any cases where you would use `.done()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `then()` instead of `done()` as `done` doesn't return a new promise.

```js
function ajax_call() {

  var ajaxCallMock = $.Deferred().resolve('A');

  return ajaxCallMock.then(function(response) {
    return 'B';
  });
}



ajax_call().then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can I simply replace the `var ajaxCallMock = $.Deferred().resolve('A');` with a `$.get()` Ajax Call? and still use `then`?